# Poisson process - calculating probabilities

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Let $\{X(t), t \geq 0 \}$ be a Poisson process with  $\lambda$ as parameter. Calculate:

- $\mathbb{P}(X(5)=3 | X(1)+X(2)=3)$
- $\mathbb{P}(X(5)-X(3)=1 | X(4)-X(2)=1)$

---

I did the first one as follows:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X(5)=3 | X(1)+X(2)=3) = \\ = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X(5)=3 , X(1)+X(2)=3)}{\mathbb{P}(X(1)+X(2)=3)} = \\ = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X(5) - (X(1)+X(2))=3 - 3 , X(1)+X(2)=3)}{\mathbb{P}(X(1)+X(2)=3)} = \\ =  \frac{\mathbb{P}(X(5 - (1+2))=0)\mathbb{P}(X(1)+X(2)=3)}{\mathbb{P} =(X(1)+X(2)=3)} = \\ = \mathbb{P}(X(2)=0)  = e^{-2\lambda}
$$
Is this correct?

What about the second one? I got kinda stuck there:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X(5)-X(3)=1 | X(4)-X(2)=1) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X(5)-X(3)=1 , X(4)-X(2)=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X(4)-X(2)=1)} = \\
= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X(5)-X(3) - (X(4)-X(2))=1 - 1 , X(4)-X(2)=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X(4)-X(2)=1)} = \\ =
\frac{\mathbb{P}(X((5-3) - (4-2))=1 - 1 , X(4)-X(2)=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X(4)-X(2)=1)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X(0)=0)\mathbb{P}( X(4)-X(2)=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X(4)-X(2)=1)} = \mathbb{P}(X(0)=0) = 1
$$
This seems fishy. I appreciate any help or affirmation that it is actually correct.

Comment: It is not true that $X(5)-X(1)-X(2)$ has the same distribution as $X(5-1-2)$

Comment: You correctly observed that $X(1)+X(2)=3$ can only imply that $X(1)=1$ and $X(2)=2$. However, $X(5)-X(1)-X(2)$ does not represent an increment of $X$ over an interval, and so, its distribution does not necessarily reduce to a simple, known distribution. (And this is also not independent from the event $\{X(1)+X(2)=3\}$.) Rather, you will simply consider $X(5)-X(2)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I don't see how $X(1) + X(2) = 3$ implies $X(1)=1$ and $X(2)=2$. Could you briefly tell me why?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake there. We can also have $X(1)=0$ and $X(2)=3$. Sorry for the confusion. The point is that the conditions $X(1)\leq X(2)$ and $X(1),X(2)\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ leave not much freedom for the pair of values $(X(1),X(2))$.

Comment: So should it be then $P(X(5)=3, X(1)+X(2)=3) = P(X(5)-X(2)=3-3)P(X(1)+X(2)=3)$ or $P(X(5)=3, X(1)+X(2)=3) = P(X(5)-X(2)=3-2)P(X(1)+X(2)=3) $?

I'm pretty confused with this exercise.

Comment: Since we know that $$A:=\{X(1)+X(2)=3\}=\{X(1)=0,X(2)=3\}\cup\{X(1)=1,X(2)=2\}=:A_1\cup A_2,$$ you will have \begin{align*}&P(\{X(5)=3\}\cap A)\\&=P(\{X(5)=3\}\cap A_1)+P(\{X(5)=3\}\cap A_2)\\&=P(X(5)-X(2)=0)P(X(1)=0,X(2)=3)\\&\quad+P(X(5)-X(2)=1)P(X(1)=1,X(2)=2)\\&=P(X(5)-X(2)=0)P(X(2)-X(1)=3)P(X(1)=0)\\&\quad+P(X(5)-X(2)=1)P(X(2)-X(1)=1)P(X(1)=1).\end{align*} This seems a bit complicated, but this is one such problem where you need to get your hands dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that $X(1)$, $X(2)$, and $X(5)$ are *not* independent random variables, since they count Poisson point-events occurring in overlapping intervals.

However, $X(1)$, $X(2){-}X(1)$, and $X(5){-}X(2)$, are independent.   Further, they are *integer-valued*, being Poisson distributed with rate parameters $\lambda, \lambda,$ and $3\lambda$, respectively.

To save type-space, let us define $X(s,t)$ as $X(t){-}X(s)$.

$$~~~X(1)\sim\mathcal P(\lambda)\\X(1,2)\sim\mathcal P(\lambda)\\~~X(2,5)\sim\mathcal P(3\lambda)$$

The event of $\{X(1){+}X(2){=}3\}$ is thus the event that $\{2X(1){+}X(1,2){=}3\}$ and as such, this event is :

$$\{X(1){=}0, X(1,2){=}3\}{\,\cup\,}\{X(1){=}1, X(1,2){=}1\}$$

Likewise the intersection of this event and $\{X(5){=}3\}$ will be :

$$\{X(1){=}0, X(1,2){=}3,X(2,5){=}0\}{\,\cup\,}\{X(1){=}1,X(1,2){=}1,X(2,5){=}1\}$$

Then you can now evaluate $\mathsf P(X(5){=}3\mid X(1){+}X(2){=}3)$ using Bayes' rule.

---

Similar reasoning will let you evaluate $\mathsf P(X(5){−}X(3){=}1\mid X(4){−}X(2){=}1)$, using the independent random variables $X(2,3)$, $X(3,4)$, and $X(4,5)$.

Comment: Looking at denominator of second example, after using Bayes' rule: $P(X(4)-X(2) = 1) \implies = P(X(4)-X(3)+X(3)-X(2)=1)$. $X(4)-X(3)$ and $X(3)-X(2)$ are independent Poisson variables with $\lambda$ parameter so the denominator will be just $P(Y = 1)$ where $Y$ ~ $Poiss(2\lambda)$. Am I correct?

Comment: I got stuck at the nominator though. We have $P(X(5)-X(4)+X(4)-X(3)=1, X(4)-X(3)+X(3)-X(2) = 1)$, and if we denote $X(5)-X(4), X(4)-X(3), X(3)-X(2)$ as $X,Y,Z$ respectively that equals to $P(X+Y=1, Y+Z=1)$. How can I progress any further?

Comment: Yes, that's the approach, @НикитаВасильев , then on applying the Law of Total Probability, you will have: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y{+}Z{=}1\mid X{+}Y{=}1)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X{+}Y{=}1,Y{+}Z{=}1)}{\mathsf P(X{+}Y{=}1)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{y=0}^1\mathsf P(Y{=}y, X{=}1{-}y,Z{=}1{-}y)}{\sum\limits_{y=0}^1\mathsf P(Y{=}y, Z{=}1{-}y)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Last question (hopefully) - how do we know that $Y$ can only take values 0 and 1? Why aren't we summing up to higher values?

Comment: Oh, because $X, Y, Z \geq 0$ so if Y was to be 2 for example, then X + Y = 1 wouldn't be possible. Right?

Comment: Exactly.  $\{X{+}Y{=}1\}=\{X{=}1,Y{=}0\}\cup\{X{=}0,Y{=}1\}$, et cetera, @НикитаВасильев